# With freeradius and PEAP-MSCHAP, how does one limit connectivity to a single group?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, freeradius, peap

I feel like jumping up and down after I got FreeRadius, samba winbind, XCA w/ ECDSA certs, Active Directory, and Ubiquiti Unifi all talking together.

Next problem, any valid account in ActiveDirectory will currently authenticate. How do I limit this to the members of a specific AD group?

One terrible way I had thought of was in in the post-auth module executing a bash script that does a quick LDAP search. Could anything bad happen from this?

## EDIT

Here's a guide to getting it all to work! https://gist.github.com/exabrial/368c279aad65cefd8c5f

Comment: You know that Windows includes its own RADIUS server, right?

Comment: It has limited functionality, which is why many people use open source solutions.

Comment: Yes, I'm well aware. I'm not going to have a system that powers our wireless rely on Windows however...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now, you need to use `rlm_ldap` (which will be considerably faster than a bash script).  We have discussed exposing winbind's APIs for group lookups, but you'd need to be using Samba 3.2.1 and a build of FreeRADIUS v3.1.x to take advantage of any features that were developed.

I'll leave you to look through (and complete) `mods-available/ldap` as the config file is pretty well documented.  After you have it customised to your LDAP server, create a symlink from `mods-available/ldap` to `mods-enabled/ldap` to enable the module.

To perform group lookups you need to compare the `LDAP-Group` attribute with a value, and then make the decision to reject the user.

Something like:

```
if (LDAP-Group != 'my_group) {
    reject
}
```

...in the inner tunnel virtual server would work.

Comment: Brilliant! I actually just ended up using the searchFilter instead: `filter = "(&(sAMAccountName={0})(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=wireless_corp,OU=Networks,OU=Groups,DC=x,DC=x,DC=x,DC=com))"`

Comment: That works too! :)

Comment: I don't know if this is simply unclear from the answer, but an `if` cannot be placed inside of a module.

Comment: Which is why the bottom of the answer explicitly states that it should be place in a virtual server.